# Showing Result returned in a Carousel RecyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a rotating carousel (using *carouselrecyclerview*) to rotate a list of images around.

The user can call a second activity and then search the images, and then return the selected image’s ID back to the MainActivity.kt.

The MainActivity.kt receives the result  (using intent) in the *onActivityResult*.
I then need to call *scrollToPosition* (from the *carouselLayoutManager*) to move the carousel to the position that was selected in the second activity.

As the call to the *carouselLayoutManager* is within the onCreate, I can’t call it from the *onActivityResult*? I have tried moving the *onActivityResult* to within the onCreate, but then the *onActivityResult* is not called when returning from the second activity.

So, how can I call the code which is within the *onCreate* from the *onActivityResult* please?

Any help really appreciated as I’m struggling on this.

**MainActivity.kt**
...

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val carouselRecyclerview = findViewById<CarouselRecyclerview>(R.id.recycler)
    val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()
    // Load the images of the Veg
    for (mycount in 0..41) {
        list.add(DataModel(VegName[mycount].image, VegName[mycount].name))
    }
    val adapter = DataAdapter(list)
    carouselRecyclerview.adapter = adapter
    val carouselLayoutManager = carouselRecyclerview.getCarouselLayoutManager()
    carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(1)
    carouselRecyclerview.setItemSelectListener(object : CarouselLayoutManager.OnSelected {
        override fun onItemSelected(position: Int) {
            var ShowIt = findViewById(R.id.textVegName) as TextView
            //Cente item
            ShowIt.text = list[position].text

        }
    })
    Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
   }

   // Move the carousel to the  position received - THIS ISN'T CALLED?
   fun setthelocation(SetThisPlace: Int ) {
        carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(SetThisPlace)
   }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val returnedfrom = VegName.find{ it.name == data?.getStringExtra("result") }

            if (returnedfrom==null)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Did not find the result returned!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Got = " + returnedfrom.id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //Need to call eiter setthelocation() or carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition???
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> As the call to the carouselLayoutManager is within the onCreate, I can’t call it from the onActivityResult?

I think you're confusing terms. There is no "call to the carouselLayoutManager" - that's a variable to assign to an object, not a function you call.

> I have tried moving the onActivityResult to within the onCreate, but then the onActivityResult is not called when returning from the second activity.

`onActivityResult` is a base-class method that is invoked for you when you use `startActivityForResult` and close the opened activity. If you "move it to within the onCreate" all you're doing is calling the base class implementation (which does nothing).

> So, how can I call the code which is within the onCreate from the onActivityResult please?

The easiest solution would be to hold on to the layout manager as a variable you can use in either `onCreate` or `onActivityResult`:

```
// Class-level property you can use in either function
private lateinit var carouselLayoutManager: LayoutManager

override fun onCreate(...) {
    // Replace local val with class-level property

    // Instead of this:
    // val carouselLayoutManager = carouselRecyclerview.getCarouselLayoutManager()

    // Do this: initialize member property to use here and in onActivityResult
    carouselLayoutManager = carouselRecyclerview.getCarouselLayoutManager()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val returnedfrom = VegName.find{ it.name == data?.getStringExtra("result") }

            if (returnedfrom==null)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Did not find the result returned!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Got = " + returnedfrom.id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                //Need to call eiter setthelocation() or carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition???

                // Now you can call this since it's a member property
                carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(...)
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - looks good now! Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

hm, for this I would recommend you to use the **NavComponent** and send your data through fragments or **registering for activity** but I don't want to confuse you and I will try to give you a solution for this problem.

I think the easiest way to solve this (in this context) would be to launch the intent as you are doing:

MainActivity.kt ->

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val carouselRecyclerview = findViewById<CarouselRecyclerview>(R.id.recycler)
    val list = ArrayList<DataModel>()
    // Load the images of the Veg
    for (mycount in 0..41) {
        list.add(DataModel(VegName[mycount].image, VegName[mycount].name))
    }
    val adapter = DataAdapter(list)
    carouselRecyclerview.adapter = adapter
    val carouselLayoutManager = carouselRecyclerview.getCarouselLayoutManager()
    carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(1)
    carouselRecyclerview.setItemSelectListener(object : CarouselLayoutManager.OnSelected {
        override fun onItemSelected(position: Int) {
            var ShowIt = findViewById(R.id.textVegName) as TextView
            //Cente item
            ShowIt.text = list[position].text
            
        }
    })
    Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
   }

   
   fun setTheLocation(SetThisPlace: Int ) {
        carouselLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(SetThisPlace)
   }

   // onNewIntent would receive the intent needed to execute your logic.
   // I wouldn't use onActivityResult because, IMO, It is dirty code and it is deprecated.
   override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (intent?.hasExtra("position") == true) {
            setTheLocation(intent.getIntExtra("position"))
        }
}
```

SearchActivity.kt ->

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        .... your code ...
        exampleOfSendingBackFunction()
    }

//Here you will send back the position to MainActivity.kt clearing all flags.
    fun exampleOfSendingBackFunction() {
         val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
             flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
             putExtras(
                "position" to yourPositionVariable
             )
         }
         startActivity(intent)
    }
```

I hope it helps :D

Comment: Really helpful  - that is really appreciated. Cheers!!!!